# Is there an elegant way to open external links up in a new tab which can be re-used?

Tags: html, javascript, hyperlink, anchor

So here is what I'm doing so far:

```
<script>
var win;
function OpenInNewTab(url )
{
  // var win;
  if (win)
  {
     win.close();
  }
  win   =window.open(url, 'myWin');
  win.focus();
}
</script>
```

And then my links are phrased like this (in order to take advantage of the Javascript function):

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="OpenInNewTab('http://www.anti-agingfirewalls.com/');">Anti-Aging Firewalls</a></li>
```

The issue is, that this solution cannot be scaled upwards for all the URLs on my page. Which means that I have to call onclick for each and every URL that I want to behave this way. Is there an elegant way to scale this solution so that I don't have to keep on typing in "onclick" for each link? (or at least reduce the effort it takes to keep on typing this in?)

Answer (score 2):

Just make those links have a normal `href` value (i.e. the URL the link will point to) and give them a `rel` attribute value of `external` to indicate you want them open in a new tab. Then just have a small JavaScript snippet search for this attribute value and then change it so the link opens in a new tab.

This is nice because the link still works even if JavaScript is disabled or otherwise fails.

```
<li><a href="http://www.anti-agingfirewalls.com/" rel="external">Anti-Aging Firewalls</a></li>

<script>
function externalLinks() {
 if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++) {
   var anchor = anchors[i];
   if (anchor.getAttribute("href") &&
       anchor.getAttribute("rel") == "external")
     anchor.target = "_blank";
 }
}
window.onload = externalLinks;
</script>
```

[This article](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/using-rel-external-instead-of-targe--new-and--blank/2609) is old but explains it quite well. It can also be simplified if you use a framework like jQuery.

Comment: This is pretty old but I don't understand the point of this, you might as well just give them both attributes rather than use JS to plop an attribute in...

Answer (score 1):

Add `target="_blank"` to your anchors is the simplest way.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">anchor</a>
```

If you don't want to modify every anchor element within the page (which is dirty work), you could add a `<base>` element in `<head>`:

```
<base target="_blank">
```

Alternatively you could use JavaScript to add that attribute in bulk on DOM ready:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].target = "_blank";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you not using target attribute here ?

a href="some like here" target="_blank">Google

Answer (score 0):

"Which can be reused," yes, absolutely.

Use the target attribute but rather than setting it to _blank, give it a name.

The following markup will open up the link into a new empty tab, so clicking three links will open three tabs:

```
<a href="/path/to/link" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

But the following markup will open up the link into **a single specified tab**, which it will be reused when subsequent links are followed:

```
<a href="/path/to/link" target="mytab">click here</a>
```

Set target to any name you want and all links to that target will predictably open in the same tab. If no tab yet exists with that name a new one will be opened.

This feature has been around since Netscape introduced frames. Today most people only use it with _self or _blank as the target, but using named targets is still as valid as ever.